# How to update multiple projects' PuTTY keys at once

Tags: git, putty, ssh-keys, tortoise-git

I have multiple projects that use the same PuTTY key in TortoiseGit. Is there a way to update all of the settings at once for all of the projects, rather than going in to the `TortoiseGit > Settings > Git > Remote > Putty key` for each project individually (for example if I change the key)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality in TortoiseGit.

The setting is stored in `GITREPO\.git\config`, so you could use a texteditor or write a small script.

---

Instead of storing the key in the git config, you could also use PuTTY sessions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29183147/3906760